# AngularJS: Dropdown in a directive with ng-options parameters

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to create a directive with a dropdown template. I try to give the value for ng-options as a parameter of the directive but the dropdown only contains the default value.

Here is a Fiddle and my code in this post :
http://jsfiddle.net/wXV6Z/6/

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope){    
    $scope.countries = [
        algeria={name:'ALGERIA', phoneCode:'213'},
        andorra={name:'ANDORRA', phoneCode:'376'},
        angola={name:'ANGOLA', phoneCode:'244'}
    ];
}

app.directive('skiTest', function() {
    return {
      'replace': true,
      'restrict': 'E',
      'scope': {
        'data': '=',
      }, 
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.options = attrs.selectOptions;
       },
        'template':'<div><select name="testSelect" ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="
      {{options}} in data"><option value="">Code</option></select></div>'
        }
      });
```

Here is the HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div>
        <h2>Without directive</h2>
        <select ng-model="code" ng-options="country.phoneCode as country.name for    country in countries">
            <option value="">Code</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>With directives</h2>
        <ski-test data="countries" select-options="country.phoneCode as country.name for country"></ski-test>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you very much if somebody can point my mistake !

Answer (score -1):

The template in the directive just needs to be this:

```
'template':'<div><select name="testSelect" ng-model="data" ng-options="c.name for c in data"><option value="">Code</option></select></div>'
```

I forked your fiddle with the change: http://jsfiddle.net/W5Ex3/